# How to access external api response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am building a payment integration from 3rd party api. After I send the request I am getting this response from terminal. What I need is to get the token in form at view. How can I access the token value?

```
Started GET "/charges/charge" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-09 14:28:48 +0300
Processing by ChargesController#charge as HTML"{\"status\":\"success\",\"systemTime\":1497007730319,\"conversationId\":\"123456789\",\"token\":\"4d4b7364-acf7-45df-9fbc-d680212ab9ba\",\"checkoutFormContent\":\"<script type=\\\"text/javascript\\\">if (typeof pay == 'undefined') {var pay = {token:\\\"4d4b7364-acf7-45df-9fbc-d680212ab9ba\\\",price:1.20,}</script>\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the json response which you are getting from payment getway. So you will need to parse it.
You can parse this json response like this

```
response = "{\"status\":\"success\",\"systemTime\":1497007730319,\"conversationId\":\"123456789\",\"token\":\"4d4b7364-acf7-45df-9fbc-d680212ab9ba\"}"
parsed_response = JSON.parse(response) # This will return you hash
token = parsed_response['token']
```